# Task Scheduler : Window can't find the specified folder

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, task-scheduler

I am running on Window 2012 OS. Whenever I am going to open Task Scheduler Service it is giving me the following error:

> Windows cannot find the specified folder.

[image: Window can't find the specified folder]

Answer (score 1):

This question already was here. The problem is in the user rights. 
From another topic: "Apparently in Windows Server 2012, the ADMINISTRATORS have the permission to create a file (here the encrypted file) while this user does not have the permission to send it. and SYSTEM user has the permission to send but not to create." [The system cannot find the file specified- Task Scheduler. Win Server 2012](https://serverfault.com/questions/689873/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-task-scheduler-win-server-2012)
So give more right to your user or log in as Administrator.